# xampp Apache not running

Tags: xampp

few weeks before my xamppp was working properly.
but today when i started it ....it failed to open its phpmyadmin page..
so i installed it again.
now its apache is not running.
another webserver is running??? whats that??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9hxF.png)
the above image shows the error.
although apache was not running ...i tried start localhost.
and this cameup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7biJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got my error.
port 80 was occupied by apache2.
removed apache2 from port 80 and it started woorking again.